# Automate keystrokes during GUI Ubuntu install

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, automation, expect

I have an automated script using buildbot to checkout, build and install from an SVN software repository. During the Ubuntu install step key strokes are required for steps like selecting a language. Right now these steps are automated by force the key stroke every 5 minutes or so until it goes thorough. i feel this isn't very efficient or robust.

```
##Installation key storkes
echo "First key press (language selection)"
VBoxManage controlvm "name_string" keyboardputscancode 1C 9C
sleep 1
echo "Second key press (install selection)"
VBoxManage controlvm "name_string" keyboardputscancode 1C 9C
sleep 300
echo "Third key press (restart VM)"
VBoxManage controlvm "name_string" keyboardputscancode 1C 9C
sleep 300
```

What I want to do is be able to make the script smarter by pressing the keystroke when it is required, rather than looping until it is ready for the input.

For command line I know I could use the expect bin for automated input. Can the same be done during the GUI Ubuntu install process? If so what would be the expect parameters i would be waiting for?

Or alternatively if there is another way I am open to trying it.

note: I want to automated the GUI process for the purposes of automated testing. By passing this by create a .deb isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Why use the *GUI* Ubuntu install (e.g. instead of the console one, or instead of customizing some Ubuntu distribution into your own one)? Did you consider making a `.deb` package doing what you want to do?

Comment: We are trying to create an automated testing environment so the more we can simulate the natural install process of the server the better. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Why? Unless you work on the installer (and are testing it), you should not care how your server is installed, but only about the state of the finally installed server (how exactly you get to that state is probably not important). I can't understand why you want to automate the GUI installation procedure.

Comment: Our installer is quite complicated and has broke a few times recently. Like I said we want to replicate the whole process the way it is intended to be used.

Comment: expect doesn't automate GUIs